# How to write an UPDATE depending on values in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, syntax, sql-update

I have a question concerning "UPDATE" in MySQL. I have two tables `table1` and `table2` which are connected `table1.id=table2.tab1`. Now, I'd like to update a value in `table2` depending on a value in `table1`. I was trying to do it like this:

```
UPDATE table2 SET table2.val='new value' 
WHERE table1.id=table2.tab1 AND table1.val='xy'
```

In other words, I would like to change the value `val` for all entries in `table2` where the corresponding entry in `table1` has the value 'xy'.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the correct syntax. You should use an update-join

```
UPDATE table2
JOIN   table1 ON table1.id = table2.tab1
SET    table2.val = 'new value' 
WHERE  table1.val = 'xy'
```

Comment: `ON` clause needs to be rectified.

Comment: `tabel2.id` to be replaced withe `table1.id`

Comment: @Samir I'm having a bad morning apparently :-( Thanks for noticing.

Comment: No worries :)))

Answer (score 5):

You should use UPDATE + JOIN statement

```
UPDATE table2 
JOIN table1 ON table1.id=table2.tab1 
SET table2.val='new value' 
WHERE table1.val='xy'
```

or subquery

```
UPDATE table2
SET table2.val='new value' 
WHERE table2.tab1 IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.val='xy'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table2
JOIN table1 ON table1.id=table2.tab1 
SET table2.val='new value' 
WHERE table1.val='xy'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE B
SET B.val='new value' 
FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B ON A.id=B.tab1
WHERE A.val='xy'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.val='new value' 
FROM table1 
    JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.tab1
WHERE table1.val='xy'
```

Comment: You cannot have `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE` query

Comment: sorry. I was mistaken for mssql.